# Como procurar por texto/frases genéricas de um certo idioma?

Tags: regex, shell-script, jade

Tenho uma centena de arquivos ".jade" que possuem diversas frases em espanhol de forma estática. Desejo fazer o mapeamento e troca dessas frases por conteúdo dinâmico baseado apenas no tipo de idioma (já que não possuo um dicionário de conteúdo prévio). Qual seria a forma mais rápida de varrer esses arquivos?

Comment: Isso lembra processamento de linguagem natural, não?

Comment: Tenta usar `dictd`... Acho que você vai chegar a uma solução. Se não, vá postando seu progresso que a comunidade ajuda.

Comment: Também não entendo muito sobre,mas leia [How is computational linguistics different from natural language processing?](https://www.quora.com/How-is-computational-linguistics-different-from-natural-language-processing).Ou os seguintes links sobre Processamento Linguagem Natural: [NER](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Named-entity+recognition), [Tutoriais muito bons de Processamento de Linguagem Natural](https://br.udacity.com/artificial-intelligence), [Competições do Kaggle](http://blog.kaggle.com/) e [Awesome Linguistics Resources for Spanish](https://github.com/dav009/awesome-spanish-nlp)